# Setting up Java Web Start for Firefox when the JDK is in a personalized location

Tags: firefox, java

Do I need a symlink to make `javaws`, that is, Java Web Start, work if I have a personalized location for my Java?

I have installed Java as follows:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" 
    "/home/user/programs/jdk6u32/bin/java" 1

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" 
    "/home/user/programs/jdk6u32/bin/javaws" 1

sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javaws

sudo ln -s /home/user/programs/jdk6u32/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so 
    /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins/libnpjp2.so
```

The last line is necessary for Firefox to find the Java plug-in.  It sets up a symlink.  It was due to advice found on `stackexchange` and I suspect I need something similar for `javaws` and if so, what would it be?

I am on ubuntu 12.04 (Precise) and Firefox 12.0 and Oracle Java 6 update 32.

Comment: @Samik, You are right. There are a few choices: download, open with Firefox or open and browse.  Opening and browsing to 'javaws' did the trick. Strangely, I never had to browse through the file system with my earlier setups but I think I had Java setup differently before. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: Ok, then posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you encounter a `.jnlp` file download, Firefox will present you with the **"open-with"** dialogue, then you can browse to the location of `javaws` and open the `.jnlp` file with it. From next time on, it'll be the default choise remembered by the browser.

Comment: That's true, but is it necesarry to launch firefox to run JNLP application? But on right click on file javaws is missing in open with other application application list :-(

Comment: just open a terminal and type `javaws <jnlp file name>`

Comment: I know, but when I can associate it with firefox I would expect, that I can associate it also with javaws...

Comment: well, there is a way to associate file-types to application, go to `/usr/share/applications/` then edit `defaults.list` to add the line `application/x-java-jnlp-file=javaws.desktop`, of course you have to create the `.desktop` file if that doesn't exist; I use icetea plugin, so mine is `icedtea-netx-javaws.desktop` but you can custom create a `.desktop` file with menu editor that points to `javaws` and kp it in that directory. Then log out and log back in.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I used this way - http://askubuntu.com/questions/235861/how-to-associate-jnlp-file-with-javaws/235872#235872

Answer (score 1):

After you launch the jnlp before, the mime type is stored into the firefox mimeType.rdf, so you could pike up it from Edit `>` Preferences > Applications, search "jnlp", then you could associate the javaws (any version of jdk or jre) with it.

Comment: Works in particular for Webex.

Answer (score 0):

Open Firefox and go to: `Edit` ➤ `Preferences` ➤ `Applications` ➤ `Java Web Start`

Pick the choice you want.

Comment: Today Java Web Start is not listed anymore, but a search for jnlp works.

Comment: I have a phone calling site which uses Java applet for web calling, I added the URL address to Web Start, but it didn't work, is there any other way to run this applet with Firefox 15.0.1?