# How to associate jnlp file with javaws

Tags: java

My actual version of java is

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_38"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_38-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.13-b02, mixed mode)
```

and it possible to run jnlp file as

```
$ javaws ContestAppletProd.jnlp
```

(it's TopCoder Contest Arena)

but I want to run it with simple double click.

When I do right click on file, there is "Open with Other Application" option, but I do not know how to add javaws here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You will need to create a `.desktop` file like described in the [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67216/unable-to-choose-default-application) for `javaws` to appear in `Open With` dialog.

In your case you will need to create a new text file in the folder `~/.local/share/applications`. Name this file whatever you want, it has to have the extension `.desktop`. The content of this file has to be the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Java 6 Web Start
Comment=Java 6 Web Start
Exec=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/bin/javaws %u
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=javaws
Categories=Application;Network;
MimeType=application/x-java-jnlp-file;
```

Please pay attention that the path to `javaws` executable in the `Exec` parameter may be different on your system. You can find out the path to your `javaws` executable by typing the following command in terminal:

```
which javaws
```

or by listing all your JDK/JRE installations with the command:

```
update-alternatives --display javaws
```

Comment: Thanks I used this Tweak and it works exactly as I expected ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to bender's answer, if you are using Chrome you may not get a chance to change the default application without first going through the file manager's "Open With other Application" step.  In my case (Chrome on XUbuntu 15.10 - XFCE), I had to:

1. Let Chrome (or whatever browser) **save** the JNLP file
2. Right click on it in the **file manager**, select "open with other application", choose application and check "Always use this".

There was already a correct jnlp application option in /usr/share/applications (multiple, in fact), so I didn't need to create my own, but it was not used until I did the above (JNLP files were associated with Firefox which didn't know what to do with them)

This is so basic that I couldn't figure it out for a while :)